# Chrome large file upload failed when SSL

Tags: angular, google-chrome, ssl, asp.net-web-api, large-files

Large file (100-600 Mb) upload failed with net::err_connection_reset in Chrome when upload with SSL. Upload in OTHER BROWSERS works fine. Upload works fine in chrome when SSL is off.

Front-end - angular 5. 
Back-end - ASP.Net WebAPI on Windows Server 2016. 
SSL certificate - CONMODO wildcard.
Front and Back are on the same domain(back is a virtual directory of the front)

Some customers claims that the large files upload being failed with Chrome. But none of comps in our office is unable to reproduce this error.
However, using the TeamView, I was able to reproduce it on the one of customer's computers. (Windows 10 enterprise, Chrome  75.0.3770.142)

Tried: 
- Disable Antivirus
- Turn the Firewall off
- change Max allowed package size, and similar settings, on the back-end
- Check AppEx Networks Accelerator(it's absent at all)
- Turn Chrome extensions off
- Run Chrome in Safe mode
- Drop Chrome to default settings
- Setup back-end as a separated application(still on same domain)
- Swithc off the UrlRewrite rules
- Comment out the uploaded files save code. 
- comment out the Authorize attribute

And only uploading with http works. In other browsers ssl works fine. It's only chrome issue.

Not all customers face this issue, but so few too. I wouldn't like to make workaround with enabling mixed content to allow upload without SSL, so maybe any body have advice how to fix it with just setting up correct Chrome or Windows settings?

Comment: Are you using http2?

Comment: Yes. I use http2. Do you think it's the point?

Comment: We have the same problem when http2 is enabled on our F5 load  balancers. We haven't had time to investigate et reverting to http1 fixed the problem

Comment: Yea, you were right. That was the reason. Thanks a lot.